# iCloud, How to View Data Activities

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud

Does anyone know how to view data in iCloud, where it is stored all activities of iPhone, iPad?

I made some phone calls from my iPhone, browsed some URLs, send out some messages and I went to icloud.com, login my account, but didn't see these activities!

Should I have some more things in order to view these activities?  Or is these some programs which can view these activities?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The type of data you are describing is not available in any public iCloud interface.

Comment: Thank you, Bgiham!  I think so, too.  But I wonder in somehow I could see those data.  Do you have any idea?